# Безопасность в виртуальной машине

Tags: безопасность, виртуальная-машина

Открыл для себя такую вещь, как виртуальная машина. Смотрю разные версии линукса. Ввожу команды, тыкаю кнопочки и смотрю, что происходит.

А вопрос прост:
Все, что находится  в виртуальной машине, остается в виртуальной машине? Я могу не беспокоиться за безопасность моего физического компьютера? Даже если все вирусы интернета в мою VMware попадут.

Comment: Иногда с виду глупые вопросы оказываются очень хорошими. :)

Comment: Существует категория вирусов специально для такого сценария - выбираться из виртуальной машины в основную (используя уязвимости виртуальной машины). Так что шансы есть.

Comment: Не бывает 100% безопасных систем. Даже в OpenBSD находят дыры. Работай внутри снапшота и не шарь явным образом (через подключённый сетевой диск с rw) дорогие себе файлы. От 99% угроз помогает. Ах да. БЭКАПЫ.

Comment: За 8+ лет работы с вирьем я не встречал ни одного, который бы пробивал VM и добирался до хоста. И коллеги про такое не рассказывали, так что шансы практически нулевые. Через шару доступ к хосту получить можно, но не надо держать в шаре ничего полезного.

Comment: В основном м.б. тут опасны сетевые черви (а они сейчас опасны?), а также  превращение вашей виртуалки в часть ботнета.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я тут почитал, тут серьезные вопросы задают, а я пришел с вопросом о том, безопасно ли страдать фигней в виртуалке. Думал, что вопрос удалят, а получил полезные ответы. Благодарю.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Эксплойтов, которые "пробивают" защиту виртуальных машин, в открытом доступе нет. Поэтому, если только вы не работаете с секретной информацией и не являетесь Сноуденом, можете считать защиту, предоставляемую виртуальной машиной, в целом надежной.

Если только вы сами ее не нарушите.

---

Прежде всего, ваша виртуалка обычно связана с вашим компьютером через виртуальную сеть. Таким образом, сетевой червь, заразивший виртуалку, получает удобную площадку для атаки на вашу основную систему. Если у вашего компьютера закрыты порты - это не будет проблемой, но если в качестве единственной меры защиты был выбран роутер с NAT - у вас проблемы.

Так что самое время разобраться с брандмауэром или файерволом и выяснить, какие разрешения вы успели дать.

---

Перспективным методом атаки на хост-систему считается эмулятор видеокарты. Если у вас есть выбор между несколькими виртуальными видеокартами - имеет смысл на виртуальной машине ограничиться стандартной виртуальной видеокартой без поддержки DirectX и OpenGL.

Также источником опасности являются комплекты "утилит виртуализации" для гостевых операционных систем - если вы будете экспериментировать с вирусами, их лучше не ставить.

В любом случае, не стоит разрешать виртуальной машине неограниченный доступ к диску.

---

Ну и последнее - надо помнить, что иногда вирусу совсем не обязательно выбираться за пределы виртуальной машины. Очевидно, если вы будете использовать одну и ту же виртуалку для экспериментов с вирусами и для оплаты чего-бы то ни было с карточки - вирус утянет ваши платежные данные так же, как бы он это сделал на реальном компьютере.

Менее очевидный сценарий - вирус, заразивший виртуалку, может включить ее в ботнет и DDOSить с нее чужой сайт. Или майнить криптовалюты за ваше электричество.

**Обновление** На процессорах Intel нашли уязвимость Meltdown, которая, в случае отсутствия закрывающих ее патчей, позволяет любому процессу произвольно читать любые места в оперативной памяти. Поэтому лучше не работайте с важными данными при запущенной виртуалке с вирусами если у вас Intel.

Answer (score -1):

В целом, если виртуальная машина настроена правильно и работает в изолированной среде, то вирус не должен иметь возможности выйти из нее и заразить основную систему. Однако, существует ряд случаев, когда это возможно:

Если виртуальная машина использует общую папку или сеть с основной системой и вирус находится в этой папке или сети, то он может заразить основную систему.

Если виртуальная машина была скомпрометирована и на ней был установлен вредоносный код, то он может использовать уязвимости в виртуальной машине для получения доступа к основной системе.

Для защиты от таких угроз рекомендуется:

Использовать изолированную среду для виртуальных машин.

Не использовать общие папки или сети между виртуальными машинами и основной системой.

Обновлять операционную систему виртуальной машины и устанавливать антивирусное ПО.

Не устанавливать на виртуальную машину неизвестные программы и не открывать подозрительные ссылки.

Регулярно создавать резервные копии важных данных вне виртуальной машины.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)