# Вирусы и руткиты в виртуальной машине

Tags: безопасность, виртуальная-машина

> Виртуальная машина, на которой предполагается запускать вирусы, должна быть максимально изолирована от основной системы. Максимально — значит не иметь с ней никаких связей насколько это возможно. Ни общих папок, ни дополнений гостевой ОС, ни расшаренных ресурсов, ни подключённых к компьютеру переносных носителей, кстати, прекрасно определяемых некоторыми типами эмуляторов, ни даже доступа к интернету.

1. Вирус может попасть минимум при наличии дополнений гостевой ОС ? А если в *Drag n Drop* и *Shared Clipboard* значение будет *disabled* ? Всё равно проникнет ? А можно установить только ту часть дополнения, которая отвечает за полный экран ?

> Не стоит забывать о руткитах, уже давно научившихся распознавать виртуальные машины.

2. А сколько виртуальных машин может обойти руткит, если в виртуальной машине стоит ещё одна виртуальная машина ?

> В крайнем случае для запуска потенциально опасного ПО следует использовать виртуальные машины с полной эмуляцией, такие как Bochs, которые хоть и не обладают стопроцентной защитой от руткитов, но всё равно в плане безопасности на порядок превосходят VMware, VirtualBox, Virtual PC, мелких уязвимостей в которых хватало и будет хватать всегда.

3. О каких мелких уязвимостях речь?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/578675/178779

Answer (score 10):

Следует различать следующие сценарии выхода вируса из виртуалки:

1. простейший случай: он может воспользоваться тем, что вы разрешили виртуалке явно (т.е. теми самыми галочками) - тут вирус может даже не понять что "взломал" другую систему;
2. он может атаковать хост-систему через виртуальную сеть как обычный сетевой червь;
3. вирус может воспользоваться эксплоитом для конкретной модели VM;
4. вирус может воспользоваться эксплоитом для процессора.

Так вот, по первому вашему вопросу. Атака вида 1 успешно предотвращается отключенными галочками. Атаки вида 3 отключенными галочками в общем случае не предотвращаются.

Однако, есть мнение что установка гостевых дополнений делает атаку 3 возможнее просто из-за увеличения количества компонентов и их сложности. Особенно сложными являются технологии виртуализации видеокарты. В частности, ранее найденные и сейчас закрытые уязвимости VirtualBox класса RCE относились именно к этой технологии.

---

Теперь о том сколько виртуальных машин может обойти руткит. Тут все просто: обойдя виртуальную машину, толковый руткит заражает систему одним уровнем выше, после чего начинает работать на ней. И начав работать, он опять делает попытку заразить те системы до которых дотянется.

Т.е. руткит может "пробить" любое число слоев виртуализации - при условии что он умеет пробивать каждый из слоев в отдельности.

---

Список известных "мелких уязвимостей" можно найти поискав в интернете "(имя продукта) CVE".

Например, вот список уязвимостей VirtualBox - https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-93/product_id-20406/Oracle-Vm-Virtualbox.html

Большинство уязвимостей были доступны только для атаки из хост-системы - но там есть и две уязвимости ([CVE-2014-0981](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2014-0981/) и [CVE-2014-0983](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2014-0983/)) которые позволяли выйти из виртуалки (как я уже говорил, обе связаны с виртуализацией видеокарты).

---

**Обновление** На процессорах Intel нашли уязвимость Meltdown, которая, в случае отсутствия закрывающих ее патчей, позволяет любому процессу произвольно читать любые места в оперативной памяти. Поэтому лучше не работайте с важными данными при запущенной виртуалке с вирусами если у вас Intel.

Answer (score 3):

Ответ прост: не парьтесь. За 10 лет работы с вирьем я не встречал (и не слышал чтобы коллеги встречали) мальварь, пытающуюся специально убежать из VM. Сеть и общие папки могут использоваться, но это не целенаправленный побег из VM.

Comment: Я же говорю: не встречали. То есть, вероятность того что вы их встретите при запуске семпла - практически нулевая.

Answer (score 3):

> А сколько виртуальных машин может обойти руткит, если в виртуальной машине стоит ещё одна виртуальная машина ?

Если заложена функциональность заражения основной ОС, то уровень вложенности не имеет значения

1. Заразили систему
2. А не в виртуальной ли мы среде?
3. Да. Заражаем "основную" систему
4. GOTO 1

А вот если чередовать операционки Windows -> Linux, то должно взлететь. А не слышал о вирусах работающими под обеими системами

Comment: А как же кроссплатформенный OpenVirus?

Comment: @bukkojot Можно ссылку?

Comment: @stackflow wine не поможет вирусу найти уязвимость EthernalBlue в линуксе :-)

Comment: @stackflow да не парьтесь вы! Не используйте рабочую машину иначе, как для работы. Все важные данные с нее бэкапьте. В случае инцидента или даже подозрения - переустановка всего и возврат с бэкапов. А работать удобнее!

Answer (score 1):

100% изоляция не реальна, т.к. файл-образ гостевой машины (вместе с вирусом) лежит в файловой системе хоста.
А если проще - удалить, как минимум, сетевой адаптер в гостевой машине...

Comment: Но ведь у вируса нет прямого доступа к файловой системе хоста.. Все известные мне escape связаны с выполнением кода в разделяемой памяти. Как сбежать через файловую систему? Есть ссылки почитать?

Comment: Во фразе "все известные мне" ключевых аж два слова: "известные" и "мне" :-)
Формально код вируса в файловой системе. Остальное дело фантазии и интеллекта...

Дальше всё зависит от Ваших задач и/или паранойи.

Comment: Ну так почитать дадите?

Comment: Это троллинг такой? Я вирусы не пишу...

Comment: На этом сайте так заведено, что ответы дают эксперты, эксперты в тех областях, в которых отвечают. Так как вы тут ответили, я счёл вероятным, что вы являетесь экспертом в области безопасности, а конкретно уязвимостей, связанных с побегом из виртуалки. Мысль в вашем ответе меня заинтересовала и я попросил доп.информации. В чём троллинг? *Не обязательно писать вирусы, чтобы уметь бороться с ними.*

Comment: С последней фразой согласен на 100%. А вот что Вы надеетесь найти *почитать* - не понятно. Даже в лаборатории Касперского Вам ничего не скажут, пока сами не столкнутся с новым эксплоитом. Объясню на пальцах: если вы на хосте с кодами запуска баллистических ракет запустите виртуалку для изучения вирусов, то рано или поздно хост сломают. А иначе - это *неуловимый Джо*...